# Different list view at folder level

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, xslt-list-view-web-part

In my custom list I use hierarchy with sharepoint folders (Projects, Agreements). 
I would like to render root folder list level and second depth level in some special way. At list items level I would like to use standard view.

How to differ rendering list view by its folder depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is not a standard feature of SharePoint. (I assume that you use SharePoint 2010). But maybe [this](http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2013/05/different-list-views-for-folders.html) link can help you.

Comment: yep, that answer is correct: using content types and view settings it can be easily set up. Another link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43686/need-a-different-views-for-folders-files-in-document-library