# How to delete columns inside a folder

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am working on a SharePoint project. The folder has three columns. I want to delete two columns.

When I try to delete the column from the page where the folders are listed, the columns inside the folder also gets deleted.

How can I delete the unwanted columns from a page that contains folders and still keep the columns inside the folder unaffected.

I tried deleting the column but then those columns inside the folder also get deleted.

Comment: what is the purpose of deleting columns? As submits suggest that is best solution.

Comment: The answer is helpfull... But i get stuk in the last point... I am using sharepoint 2013 and i cannot ser any option for show this view... Can u please help

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want one view at the root level and a different view inside the folder.

To create different views for root and folders do the following.

1. Create the view to show at the root set it as default view
2. Create the view to show inside folders set it as default view, but also down in the folders section set `Show this view` to `In folder of content type: <Your folder content type>`
3. Go back to the root view and change `Show this view` to `In the top-level folder`

[Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43686/need-a-different-views-for-folders-files-in-document-library)