# How can I create different view based on Different Folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, view

I want to Create My List/Library view based on different folder.

For Ex:

There are different folders Like "folder1", "folder2","folder3". Now I want to create view for every folder. How Can I achieve it?

Comment: If you are creating views using UI, then add filter to match the Folder Names. And if using code, make a query.

Comment: I am creating UI based view. But If I filter based on folder name so it will not display the records under it

Answer (score 0):

If you want view based on Folder please check below reference link.

Reference : [Need a different views for Folders & Files in Document Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43686/need-a-different-views-for-folders-files-in-document-library)

Hope it will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create three views like below:

**Folder 1 View**

Filter "Name" equal to "Folder1"

**Folder 2 View**

Filter "Name" equal to "Folder2"

**Folder 3 View**

Filter "Name" equal to "Folder3"

Filter condition should be like below for all the three views:

[image]

We can see that three views are created and based on the view selection folder is getting displayed in the content area:

[image]

Note:

- The above UI based view creation can also be done thru the coding using camel query builder.